# How to make text in a middle of a line : ------- Text example -------

Tags: line

I would like to make horizontal lines at each side of some text. I tried to use `\rule`, but I want the total lenght (text + line) to be the same (and user defined) for several line-text, so the line lenght depends on the text lenght. Example :

[image: Tree text-lines]

Is there a package or a native LaTeX command to do the trick ?

Comment: Possibly this: `\noindent\hrulefill\raisebox{-.3\ht\strutbox}{Short Text}\hrulefill\par`

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-to-hrule

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes : This works ! I have created a command with text side margins for more convenience :

`\newcommand*{\lrrule}[1]{\hrulefill\hspace*{2.5mm}\raisebox{-.3\ht\strutbox}{#1}\hspace*{2.5mm}\hrulefill}`

Comment: Another closely related question: [Center text between horizontal lines extending to the margin on either side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243651).

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\begin{document}        
\noindent
\xrfill[0.7ex]{1pt}Text\xrfill[0.7ex]{1pt}

\noindent
\xrfill[0.7ex]{1pt}This is a longer text\xrfill[0.7ex]{1pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me "Undefined control sequence". I'm using ShareLaTeX, maybe it comes from that (unknown package or something) ?

Comment: Ah, I see. Use `\xrfill` instead of `\xhfill`. See edited answer

Answer (score 5):

Here, I take the definition of `\hrulefill`, and add height/width/depth specification to the `\hrule`, allowing it to be customized (I call it `\myrulefill`).  Also, by avoiding an earlier suggested `\raisebox`, the text sits on the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\dotfill#1{\cleaders\hbox to #1{.}\hfill}
\makeatletter
\def\myrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height .7ex width 1ex depth -0.6ex\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\myrulefill Short Text\myrulefill\par

\noindent\myrulefill This is Longer Text\myrulefill

\noindent\myrulefill What you see is very long text\myrulefill

\makeatletter
\def\myrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height .9ex width 1ex depth -0.2ex\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\noindent\myrulefill Short Text\myrulefill\par

\noindent\myrulefill This is Longer Text\myrulefill

\noindent\myrulefill What you see is very long text\myrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%% Define a new command as Steven B. Segletes suggested:
%% Use the length \rlength to have a default width.
\newlength{\rlength}\setlength{\rlength}{5cm}
\newcommand{\ruletext}[2][\rlength]{%
  \noindent%
  \parbox{#1}{%
    \noindent\hrulefill\raisebox{-.3\ht\strutbox}{#2}\hrulefill\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\ruletext{Foo}

\ruletext{Bar Baz}

%% Change the width of the box.
\ruletext[3cm]{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Results in

[image]